# Generic Issue with Tkinter to create a GUI Application in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, tkinter

I have a general problem, which I sketch here as the details will be too involved to post here. I know the problem statement, is a bit fuzzy and I may need to go back and forth with an expert in this site. (unfortunately, it is difficult to put everything up here based on the type of the problem. I will really appreciate any help).

I am trying to create a GUI application using Tkinter. The way I am doing is as follows. I have a background script (say back.py) which has the data loaded, calculations done and graph plotted.

Now the way I want to do is that I have a GUI script which uses Tkinter and calls the back.py ( using import). Now I have the window created, with a button. This is where I am stuck. I want to click the button to trigger the background script and generate the plots ( which the background script generates).

After this I want to close the plot and want my GUI to pop up some buttons to input me some parameters. These parameters will be input to the next part of the back.py code ( I chose the parameters based on the plot). When I again click the button ( with the parameters selected), I want to start running the background code again which will output me a file.

How can I do this?. A general rough idea will be helpful.

Let me put an example as much as I can:( at least the skeleton of the code)
 I have a background file say (a.py) and gui file ( say g.py)

a.py

```
import ...

def progA():
    # reading a file
    # doing something and generating a plot from the file
    # Once the GUI's first part is done generating the plot, I need to close that 
    # plot (or button)  and then  click the button 2 to run the next function

def progB(y1, y2,y3):
    #run a code...  and generate an output file
```

g.py

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

class GUI ():

    def create widgets(self):
        #....

    def create panel(self):
        #create buttons
        panel1 = ...
        btn1 = Button(panel1, text="yyyyy", command=progA)
        btn1.pack() 

    def create_panel1(self):
        #create buttons
        panel1 = ...
        btn1 = Button(panel1, text="yyyyy", command=progA)
        btn1.pack() 

    def create_panel2(self):
        #create buttons
        panel2 = ...
        btn2 = Button(panel1, text="yyyyy", command=progB)
        btn2.pack() 

All_Entries = []

window = Tk()
D=GUI(window)
window.mainloop()

import a
runprogram1 = a.progA()
runprogram2 = a.probB(x, y, z)
```

My question is now, does the above makes sense? So I have a couple of questions:

1. How will I ensure that when I close the plots (from the output of progA), that the second button will show up?
2. Where can I input the there values of the parameters in the second button?

Comment: This sounds pretty linear to me, so I wonder where the problem is. Of course everything would be easier if there was a [mcve] of the issue in the question.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question, by filling out some more details as much as I can.  Please help.

Comment: Well that is very coarse. So I think I can only say as much as this: consider to use a globally accessible variable to store the data you need to exchange. And if you intend to use pyplot to create the figure, show it via `fig.show()` instead of `plt.show()` not to block the tk window.

Comment: Thanks again. But me being just starting OOP/GUI, I am novice. I did not get that. How to make sure to have the data globally accessible. Also how will I put the three buttons to input three variables which willbe taken in the second program?

Comment: Being a novice you may decide to start with a project that is a little smaller. And proceed step by step. Can you create a button in let it print something to the console, then let it plot something. Then let the plot print something. Read about global and local scopes in python and let your plot store something instead of printing. etc..

Comment: If you are trying to work with a class/OOP I would argue against the use of global variables. Instead I would use class attributes and methods to get the job done.